# MonoDroid and TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to convert the current time to Central Standard Time. With Mono and .NET, these both work.

```
TimeZoneInfo cst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, cst);
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, cst);
```

With MonoDroid 3.0.4, the first one give this error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: Kind propery of dateTime is Utc but the sourceTimeZone does not equal TimeZoneInfo.Utc
  at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (DateTime dateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, System.TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (DateTime dateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

and the second gives this error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: destinationTimeZone
  at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (DateTime dateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo     sourceTimeZone, System.TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (DateTime dateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Same problems with TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId.

Anyway to get the current time in different timezones with MonoDroid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible workaround is to call the three-parameter version yourself:

```
var zoned = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, cst);
```

EDIT: `FindSystemTimeZoneById` *should* throw a `TimeZoneNotFoundException` if it doesn't find the zone you're interested in, but I wonder whether in this case it's just returning `null`.

It's possible that the time zone IDs on MonoDroid are the TZDB ones, in which case you could try using:

```
TimeZoneInfo cst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Chicago");
```

Comment: Same problem, System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: destinationTimeZone
I think I've tried every version of ConvertTime and ConvertTimeBySystemZoneId

Comment: @cuda: Possibly stupid question - have you validated that `cst` is non-null? (See my edit for a suggestion...)

Comment: @cuda: It shouldn't have to occur to you - it shouldn't be returning null :( Could you file a bug against Mono for this?

Comment: will do. Interesting that "America/Chicago" throws a TimeZoneNotFoundException on .NET 4.0.

Comment: @cuda: That's because .NET doesn't use TZDB time zone names, which is annoying in itself. My Noda Time project supports both BCL and TZDB time zones: http://noda-time.googlecode.com